# StreamWriter/Reader reading and then immediately writing causes exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, io

I need to read a number from a file and then increment the number and update the same file just for debugging purposes. I wrote this code and to my surprise it throws an exception (it is just for debugging but nonetheless I would like to get to the bottom of this):

> The process cannot access the file '' because it is being used by another process.

Code:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Log.txt");

int newTotal = 0;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    var total = reader.ReadLine();

    if (total != null)
    {
        newTotal = int.Parse(total) + 1;
    }
}

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path, false))
{
    // I added AutoFlush because I read somewhere on SO 
    // this will write to disk immediately
    writer.AutoFlush = true; 
    writer.Write(newTotal);
}
```

Then I wanted to narrow the issue down to either reading or writing, so I did this:

```
string path = Server.MapPath("~/Log.txt");

int newTotal = 0;

try
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
    {
        var total = reader.ReadLine();

        if (total != null)
        {
            newTotal = int.Parse(total) + 1;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw new System.Web.HttpException("During reading...");
}

try
{
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(path, false))
    {
        writer.AutoFlush = true;
        writer.Write(newTotal);
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    throw new System.Web.HttpException("During writing...");
}
```

I am getting this so this tells me it happens during both but randomly:

```
During reading...
During writing...
During reading...
During writing...
During reading...
During reading...
During writing...
During writing...
During writing...
During writing...
During writing...
During reading...
During reading...
During reading...
```

Just a note that this code is in the `Controller` of an MVC app within this method:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
    base.Initialize(requestContext);
    // Code is here
}
```

I used *Process Explorer* and nothing else is using the file.

**Question**: I am disposing things here so why the exception?

At first I thought perhaps there is a delay in disposing the `reader` but in that case all exceptions should be about `reader` but this is not the case. Also, below will also give the same exception:

```
this.path = Server.MapPath("~/Log.txt");

var total = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(this.path);
int newTotal = 0;

if (total != null)
{
    newTotal = int.Parse(total) + 1;
}

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(this.path, newTotal.ToString());
```

There are no threads. Just HTTP GET (regular and via AJAX).

**EDIT**

This happens during load testing using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: Is your file supposed to be a rolling log, or is it literally just a file with one number on it?

Comment: @maccettura Just a stupid file with 1 number on it...for debugging purposes. I was trying to fix some other (totally unrelated issue).

Comment: I feel like it would be easier to just use `var input = File.ReadAllText("some/path");`  Then `int.TryParse()`, then write the int back with `File.WriteAllText()`

Comment: @maccettura Maybe. But I still want to know why this is happening.

Comment: What I am trying to say is that your exception could potentially be avoided by not handling the streamreaders yourself and using the preferred `File.Etc` methods.

Comment: @maccettura I understand what you are saying. But what if I had to use the approach in my question (it is a valid approach--unless someone can tell me otherwise), why am I getting an exception. Sure I can use `File` but I still am curious to know why this exception.

Comment: @maccettura even `File` does not work. Just an FYI...

Comment: *There are no threads. Just HTTP GET (regular and via AJAX).* - Actually web apps always can have multiple threads if you send requests at the same time (which AJAX can do). It would be helpful if you would provide a sample of the AJAX request so this can be replicated.

Comment: @NightOwl888 each ajax will have a dedicated thread and they will not affect each other. The same as a regular request. Am I wrong?

Comment: But if you are making multiple requests (since you use load test) - multiple threads will try to read/write the same file at the same time, so exception is not surprising?

Comment: @Evk but the load test will go through the asp.net pipeline and a dedicated thread from the pool will serve it. Things are not shared between requests unless they are static. If this is not the case, then this is "news" to me.

Comment: But file is on your filesystem, it's shared resource, so I don't see how what you said changes anything. Each request is on dedicated thread, and from that threads they all read/write the same file (I don't mean same FileStream instance or something - same file on your drive).

Comment: Separate requests are handled on separate threads. When those threads all hit the code the tries to read/write the file at the same time you will have file locking conflicts. File locking is not trivial to implement. Have a look at [File Locking (Read/Write) in ASP.NET Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/430879/file-locking-read-write-in-asp-net-application) for some ideas.

Comment: Maybe "is being used by another process" message confusing you. If so - you should know the same message is produced when you try to access file used by another thread in the same process too.

Comment: @Evk Thanks but no that is not confusing to me and I am pretty clear on what the error means. I think NightOwl888 may have a point but this is very, very strange if he is right. ASP.NET does not share anything between requests or else every single class would need to be threadsafe. This means everything I have ever known about web apps goes to s**t.

Comment: Your understanding is fine in general, but filesystem is out of control for asp.net, it's managed by OS. There is just no way it can somehow automatically resolve this problem for you. Request A opens file for exlusive writing, OS puts a lock on it. Request B wants to open for reading - OS rejects. There is nothing asp.net can do with that. Only you can resolve it by managing how you open that file and when.

Comment: @Evk Not arguing but I need to understand this. But that means other code within that class would also need to be threadsafe. Which means all classes within asp.net need to be threadsafe. Also please see [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benchr/2008/09/03/does-asp-net-magically-handle-thread-safety-for-you/) which I mentioned earlier: static things are not threadsafe.

Comment: @CodingYoshi - Thread safety is a different issue. Opening a separate instance of a class on a different thread is guaranteed to be thread safe. You only have to worry about thread safety when you make a singleton class. The thing is that *files* are *single* resources so sharing them between parallel web server requests means you need to have a thread-safe file locking strategy. One way to do that is to make a singleton file manager class that ensures only one write thread can enter at a time, but you will have contention between requests which will not scale well.

Comment: @CodingYoshi - A more scaleable approach is to use a queue to eliminate the contention between requests. It really all depends on what your goal is. The approach to use heavily depends on *how much* contention there will be on the file, which isn't clear from your question.  If you just want to learn how to implement this, that is one thing, but most developers under time constraints would just go for a tried and true NoSQL or SQL database which has already worked out a file locking strategy than to roll their own which is not trivial to implement or debug.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this problem and I solved it by adding a while loop.

Try doing this and see if it solves your problem.

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(path))
{
    while (reader.Peek() > -1) 
    {
        var total = reader.ReadLine();
        newTotal = int.Parse(total) + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: From MSDN about Peak's return: `An integer representing the next character to be read, or -1 if there are no characters to be read or if the stream does not support seeking.` So if there are no characters, I will keep reading forever. And what about writing?

Comment: It's within a while loop... if a -1 comes back (there are no characters to be read) it will stop... it performs what is within the while loop otherwise and ReadLine() moves it to the next line. I'm confused by your comment, please test it out.

Comment: Ok fair. However, the exception will be thrown at this line `using(var reader = new StreamReader(path))`, it will not even reach the `while`. Plus if it cannot `Peek` then it will skip and I will miss that read and my `total` will be off.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is NOT because of:

1. GC not deallocating and the code reaching writing before `reader` is collected. I tested the exact code with a console application and the issue cannot be replicated.
2. This is not due to threading (**except for one caveat**) because I am not creating any threads. Within ASP.NET each request gets assigned a thread from the pool and an instance of the class with be created for each thread<sup>1</sup>. If there are class level things (`static`), then they obviously will not be threadsafe. They will be shared. But this code is not within a static context.

**Here is the caveat:**

When using a browser, this issue was never replicated. I also did something simple like this:

```
protected override void Initialize(RequestContext requestContext)
{
     System.IO.File.AppendAllText(tPath, "Thread enter and ID is: " + 
         System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + Environment.NewLine);
     // Placed all code here
     System.IO.File.AppendAllText(tPath, "Thread exit and ID is: " + 
         System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Now with the above code, when the requests are made through a browser, as expected, the contents of the file are as shown below. Notice every entry is **synchronous**:

```
Thread enter and ID is: 35
Thread exit and ID is: 35
Thread enter and ID is: 11
Thread exit and ID is: 11
Thread enter and ID is: 29
Thread exit and ID is: 29
Thread enter and ID is: 36
Thread exit and ID is: 36
Thread enter and ID is: 27
Thread exit and ID is: 27
Thread enter and ID is: 11
Thread exit and ID is: 11
Thread enter and ID is: 29
Thread exit and ID is: 29
Thread enter and ID is: 8
Thread exit and ID is: 8
Thread enter and ID is: 11
Thread exit and ID is: 11
Thread enter and ID is: 36
Thread exit and ID is: 36
...
```

But during Visual Studio load testing, the contents are like this and the entry into the method is **not synchronous**:

```
Thread enter and ID is: 12
Thread exit and ID is: 12
Thread enter and ID is: 29
Thread enter and ID is: 49
Thread enter and ID is: 51
Thread exit and ID is: 29
Thread exit and ID is: 51
Thread enter and ID is: 48
Thread exit and ID is: 48
Thread enter and ID is: 57
Thread exit and ID is: 57
Thread enter and ID is: 17
Thread exit and ID is: 17
Thread enter and ID is: 55
Thread exit and ID is: 55
Thread enter and ID is: 42
Thread exit and ID is: 42
Thread enter and ID is: 47
Thread enter and ID is: 55
...
```

**Conclusion**

In conclusion, when doing a load test with Visual Studio, the call behavior is not the exact same as it would be from a browser. For some reason, each thread is not given its own instance of the class. I have no idea why but if someone does, please chime in. I think this is bullcrap if you ask me: *How can I do a load test if it is doing something which is totally against the ASP.NET architecture?*

<sub>1. [Thread safety ASP.NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benchr/2008/09/03/does-asp-net-magically-handle-thread-safety-for-you/)</sub>

Comment: You just don't refresh browser fast enough, so requests come one after another. In real usage - many people will visit site and of course their requests will be processed in parallel, just like in load test. It's _load_ test all - simulates just that.